# Sharepoint Download creates the file but the filestream does not download

Tags: sharepoint, download

Dim fullFilePath = "thefullPathInSharepoint"

```
    Dim webMes As String = ""
    Dim _context = New ClientContext(New Uri("https://twmetals1.sharepoint.com/sites/gbu/"))
    Dim web = _context.Web
    Try
        _context.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", MySecurity.stringToSecureString("Thepassword"))
        Dim _web As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web = _context.Web

        _context.Load(web, Function(webSite) webSite.Title)
        _context.ExecuteQuery()
        Console.WriteLine(_web.Title)
        Dim _display As String = _web.Title
        Dim _file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(New Uri(fullFilePath).AbsolutePath)
        _context.Load(_file)

        Try
            _context.ExecuteQuery()

            Dim destfileName = "C:\theNewFile2.xlsx"
            Dim fileRef = _file.ServerRelativeUrl
            Dim fileInfo As FileInformation = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(_context, _file.ServerRelativeUrl)
            _context.ExecuteQuery()

            Try
                Dim fileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(destfileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
                fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            Try
                _context.ExecuteQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                webMes = ex.Message
            End Try
        Catch ex1 As Exception
            webMes = ex1.Message
        Finally
        End Try
    Catch ex2 As Exception
        webMes = ex2.Message
    End Try

    Return webMes
```

This all seems very straight forward. I have tried C# and VB but they both create the file but do not populate the data from the excel file into the newly created one. Thank you so much for any help!!!